# Nginx Django after add SSL get too many redirects error

Tags: django, ssl, nginx

Fist of all sorry for my bad english.

I'm having a problem configuring LetsEncrypt in my webapp, i make it work now i can access using https://www.myproject.com but if i try to use www.myproject.com, myproject.com or even https://myproject.com without the www i always get the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

This is my nginx config in /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name myproject.com www.myproject.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-myproject.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
            root /home/user;
    }

    location /media/ {
            root /home/user;
    }

    location /.well-known {
            alias /home/user/myproject/.well-known;
    }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

I check a lot of questions like mine but in php projects try the solutions but still not found one to solve my problem.

if helps i have to say that i have cloudflare free configure for my domain

Thanks!

FIX: If you use cloudflare in your web when you install SSL certificates have to put the SSL cloudflare configuration in Full or Full(strict).

Comment: I Fix it changing the CloudFlare options SSL config in Crypto have to be in Full or Full(strict) to make it work!!!

Comment: You can also use always https in cloudflare i'll fix the issue and redirect all the trafic to https when setting the https into a flexible mode.